# Cannot find 'Recipe' in scope

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a beginner developer and i am trying to use my extension "Recipe" in Recipe model as a list in my HomeView. I am getting the error Cannot find 'Recipe' in scope and i cannot figure out why.

HomeView:

```
import SwiftUI

[struct HomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(Recipe.all) { recipe in       "Cannot find Recipe in scope"
                Text(recipe.name)
                    .navigationTitle("My Recipes")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}

RecipeModel:

import Foundation

enum Category: String {
    case breakfast = "Breakfast"
    case soup = "Soup"
    case salad = "Salad"
    case appetizer = "Appetizer"
    case main = "Main"
    case side = "Side"
    case dessert = "Dessert"
    case snack = "Snack"
    case drink = "Drink"
}

struct Recipe: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let description: String
    let ingredients: String
    let directions: String
    let category: Category.RawValue
    let datePublished: String
    let url: String
    
    
}

extension Recipe {
    static let all: \[Recipe\] = \[
        
        Recipe(name: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad", image: "https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/greekbroccolisalad-667x1000.jpg", description: "Greek Broccoli Pasta Salad combines tender fusilli pasta with fresh vegetables and a tangy herb dressing. This is the perfect dish to serve with grilled meats, or pack for a picnic or barbecue!", ingredients: "1 pound rotini pasta, 4 cups broccoli florets cut into 1-inch pieces (8 ounces), 1 ½ cups cherry tomatoes cut in half, 1 cup diced green bell pepper 1/2-inch dice, ½ cup diced red onion ¼-inch dice, ½ cup kalamata olives sliced, ¼ cup crumbled Feta cheese.", directions: "1. Bring a large pot of water to a boil and add the pasta and cook according to package directions. 2. The last two minutes add in the broccoli. Drain and rinse in cold water. 3. In a large serving bowl toss together pasta, broccoli, tomatoes, bell pepper, onion, and olives. 4. ", category: "Salad", datePublished: "7-25-2021", url: "https://therecipecritic.com/greek-broccoli-pasta-salad/"),][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Above is the screenshot of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The second screen shot shows perfectly your mistake. You created the RecipeModel file (and the RecipeCard file, and their containing folders) in the wrong place, as part of the test target, BetterRecipesTests. You needed to create them as part of the app target, BetterRecipes.

Note that the issue is not merely the physical location in the hierarchy but the target membership. You'd need to change that in the file inspector.